# Как задать margin элементу управления

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

При добавлении на карту элемента можно задать position, вопрос, как задать margin?

```
map.controls.add(customControl, {
    float: 'none',
    position: {
        top: 10,
        left: 10
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что при большом разрешении элемент отображается нормально, но при сужении есть отступы сверху и слева, т.к. задали position, а вот справа и снизу прижимается к краю. Не нравится мне это))) 

Вот мой пример...
https://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/Lse8v72p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Можете подписаться на [`map.container@sizechange`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-sizechange) и рассчитывать ширину контрола самостоятельно.